# creating a discord invite link via php and curl?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

Is there a way to link through the discord API and create a invite link? I'm planning to store the link in a DB and only specific users will be able to join based on the unique 1 time link created by the discord bot. I plan to have this be hooked up into a front end admin panel so I can keep track of all the links and who they belong to and if the link was already used or not.  Not really looking into posting message or such just need it for creating unique links.

Comment: please, add some demo code.

Answer (score 1):

Found this while question while trying to do it myself.  Here is what I came up with, feel free to give it a try.

Prerequisites:

a)  Ensure you have setup a BOT and invited it to your server. You will need the 'BOT_TOKEN' to authenticate. (See: https://codeburst.io/discord-bot-tutorial-2020-a8a2e37e347c) for a nice tutoral

b) You will also need to get your Channel ID by turning on 'developor options, right clicking on your channel and seleting 'CopyID'  (See: [https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/discord/#:~:text=In%20The%20Discord%20application%20go,channel%20ID%20(Copy%20ID)](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/discord/#:%7E:text=In%20The%20Discord%20application%20go,channel%20ID%20(Copy%20ID))) for an example.

Note: I put some code to keep from calling the API too many times, adjust as needed.

This is for 'API v6'

```
define("INVITE_FILE","/tmp/lastinvite.dat");
define("INVITE_STALE",4500); //seconds
define("BOT_TOKEN","{PASTE YOUR BOT TOKEN HERE}");
define("CHANNEL_ID","{PASTE YOUR CHANNEL ID HERE!}");
function invite_discord($options)
{
//prevent too many messages
$f=file_exists(INVITE_FILE);
if ($f == false) $last=time()-500000;
else $last=@filemtime(INVITE_FILE);
$now=time();
$el=$now - $last;
if ($el < INVITE_STALE)
 {
 return file_get_contents(INVITE_FILE);

} // not last invite
// Replace the URL with your own webhook url
$url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" . CHANNEL_ID . "/invites";

$inviteobj=json_encode($options, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
     array( "Authorization: Bot " . BOT_TOKEN,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Referer: https://discordapp.com/channels/@me'
));

 curl_setopt_array( $ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $inviteobj]);


$response = curl_exec( $ch );
$works=strpos($response,'{"code":' );
if ($works === false) return "";
file_put_contents(INVITE_FILE,$response);
curl_close( $ch );
return $response;
}
```

You can use the function like this.

```
$inviteobj = [
    /*
     * How long link should last (0 for forever)
     */
    "max_age" => 0,
    /*
     * The total users that can use the invite (here I use 1)
     */
    "max_uses" => 1,
   ];
$r=invite_discord($inviteobj);
$inviteresp=json_decode($r,true);
$code=$inviteresp["code"];
echo "Invite Code is $code\n";
```